# Group By in DataTables server side

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I used datatables server side. But i got problem when my query needed group by for selecting data. How to group by in datatables server side? it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. But you need to use "group by" as a subquery. Otherwise, pagination/data counts will be messed up.

```
SELECT category_name, total_length
FROM (Select 
  any_value(category.name) as category_name, 
  concat(sum(length), \" minutes\") as total_length 
from film 
left join film_category on film_category.film_id = film.film_id
left join category on film_category.category_id = category.category_id
group by category.category_id) as Table1
```

If you dont want to waste your time with coding, check this link. this is an example how to do it with datatables library.

https://datatables.ozdemir.be/group-by

```
<?php
require '../../../vendor/autoload.php';
use Ozdemir\Datatables\Datatables;
use Ozdemir\Datatables\DB\MySQL;
include "../../_config.php";
$dt = new Datatables(new MySQL($config));
$dt->query("Select 
  any_value(category.name) as category_name, 
  concat(sum(length), \" minutes\") as total_length 
from film 
left join film_category on film_category.film_id = film.film_id
left join category on film_category.category_id = category.category_id
group by category.category_id");
echo $dt->generate();
```

Comment: It gives an error "Unknown column 'SUM' in 'field list'"

Comment: You should use an alias for sql functions